# WordPress - Send email from dashboard widget

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I'm working on a dshboard widget for WordPress. I've successfully added it using `add_meta_box` function and also tried using `wp_add_dashboard_widget` and I'm able to see my custom HTML code. I need now to send an email when the submit button is clicked, is this possible?I'm looking to the wordpress codex, but there is no trace of how to manage the widget content, can anyone help me please?

```php
    public function setup_ticketing_widget()
    {

        // Remove Welcome panel.
        remove_action( 'welcome_panel', 'wp_welcome_panel' );

        // Remove all Dashboard widgets.
        global $wp_meta_boxes;
        unset( $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard'] );

        //
        //wp_add_dashboard_widget( 
        //    'ict-support-ticket', 
        //    __('Richiesta ticket di supporto'), 
        //    [$this, 'ticketing_widget_content'],
        //);

        
        // Add custom dashbboard widget.
        add_meta_box( 'dashboard_widget_example',
            __( 'Richiesta ticket di supporto'),
            [$this, 'ticketing_widget_content'],
            'dashboard',
            'side',  // $context: 'advanced', 'normal', 'side', 'column3', 'column4'
            'high',     // $priority: 'high', 'core', 'default', 'low'
        );
    }

    /*
    *   
    */
    public function ticketing_widget_content()
    {
        ?>
            <div id="form-wrappe">
                <label id="form-label">Request Type</label>
                <select name="support_request_type" id="form-input">
                    <option value="">-----</option>
                    <option value="">1</option>
                    <option value="">2</option>
                    <option value="">3</option>
                </select>            
            </div>
            <div id="form-wrapper">
                <lable id="form-label">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="support_request_from" id="form-input">
            </div>
            <div id="form-wrapper">
                <label id="form-label">Messsage</label>
                <textarea name="support_request_message" rows="10" id="form-input"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div id="form-wrapper">
                <button id="submit-button">Invia ticket</button>
            </div>
            <style>
                option {
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                }
                #form-label {
                    display: block;
                }
                #form-input {
                    width: 100%;
                }
                #help-text {
                    display: block;
                    font-size: 1em !important;
                }
                #submit-button {
                    width: 100%;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                }
                #form-wrapper {
                    margin-top: 1em;
                    margin-bottom: 1em;
                }
            </style>
        <?php
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I've created a rest route that will be called from the code using the following code

```php
    public function submit_support_ticket( WP_REST_Request $request )
    {
        $request_type = sanitize_text_field( $request->get_param('reqType') );
        $request_issuer = sanitize_email( $request->get_param('issuerEmail') );
        $request_message = sanitize_textarea_field( $request->get_param('reqMessage') );

        var_dump( $request_type, $request_issuer, $request_message );

        switch( $request_type ){
            case '1':
                $subject = '... WordPress';
                break;
            case '2':
                $subject = '... WordPress';
                break;
            case '3':
                $subject = '... WordPress';
                break;
            case '4':
                $subject = '...';
                break;
        }
        //wp_mail( $to:string|array, $subject:string, $message:string, $headers:string|array, $attachments:string|array )

        $to = 'demo@example.org';
        $headers[] = 'From: Ticketing System WordPress <demo@example.org>';
        $headers[] = 'Cc: User 1 <demo@example.org>';
        $headers[] = 'Cc: User 2 <demo@example.org>';
        $headers[] = 'Cc: User 3 <demo@example.org>';

        if( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $request_message, $headers ) ){
            return [
                'status' => 'success',
                'message' => 'Email sent'
            ];
        } else {
            return [
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'Email not sent'
            ];
        }
    }
```

In my class construct I've used the `rest_api_init` hook to register the route and this is the JS script part I've added to the function that is responsable to send the ajax request to the route

```
            <script>
                const siteURL = window.location.origin
                const requestType = document.getElementById('request-type');
                const issuerEmail = document.getElementById('issuer-email');
                const requestMessage = document.getElementById('request-message');
                const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit-button');

                //
                submitButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    console.log(siteURL, requestType.value, issuerEmail.value, requestMessage.value);
                    
                    fetch(`${siteURL}/wp-json/support/ticketing/send-request`, {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            reqType: requestType.value,
                            issuerEmail: issuerEmail.value,
                            reqMessage: requestMessage.value
                        })
                    }).then( (res) =>  {
                        console.log(res)
                    }).catch( e => console.log(e) )  
                });
            </script>
```

I've noticed that the callback that is responsable to send the email will be not fired. Is there something wrong into the implementation?

Comment: Sure it is "possible" ... You currently don't actually have a form there, so you would need to use JavaScript/AJAX to submit this - or you add an actual form element, to "normally" submit this. You could just submit it to the current page URL, and then have some code in your functions.php check if any POST parameters specific to that particular form are set, so that you know that you need to process this data at this point and send the mail. Or you could set up a proper AJAX endpoint for it using the standard WP methodology for that.

Comment: So I will need to add a form element and submit to the same page, If I understend, I can use a function inside my oop plugin that will intercept and manage the request?

Comment: I don't know what exactly your "oop plugin" is supposed to be, so I can't answer that for sure. But if you write your own plugin, then you'll need to see to it that its methods are getting invoked somehow, that will not happen all by itself.

Comment: @CBroe I've created a rest route that will be responsable to manage the form submission using ajax.